# Disable GWT Request Factory Obfuscation

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

With GWT 2.4 obfuscation is performed for RequestFactory interfaces.

Is there any way to disable this?  Specifically I am looking to get at the names of actual RF method names in the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

If you run the "ValidationTool" as an annotation processor, you can get the generated source of the deobfuscator written to a file, where you'll find the mappings between obfuscated names and actual domain classes and methods/properties.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable obfuscation in all module if add "-style PRETTY|DETAILED" in GWT compiler options

```
<java classname="com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler" classpathref="gwt.classpath" fork="true" failonerror="true">
    <jvmarg="-Xmx256M"/>
    <arg value="-style" />
    <arg value="PRETTY" />
    <arg value="-out" />
    <arg value="../html" />
    <arg value="YourModule"/>
</java>
```